# Boyd-like template

Tags: templates

I'm not able to find a template that looks like ["Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) online. Basically, I love the style and would like it for my assignments, essays, reports, thesis, etc... Perhaps, I can get some help to create a basic template.

Comment: well it was set via latex/dvips using the standard computer modern fonts so shouldn't take that much to set up.

Comment: I find it rather unattractive: the header rule should always cover the section numbers or never. If you look at pages 2 and 3 facing each other, you'll see what I mean.